# Having Issues mapping Json to swift objects

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to map a JSON to an object I created but I keep running into difficulties

[this is what the JSON looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1QH3.png)

I tried doing this

```swift
    var overview: NYTimesBestsellerOverview?

        guard let gitUrl = URL(string: URLConstants.BESTSELLER_LIST_OVERVIEW) else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: gitUrl) { (data, response
            , error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let overview = try decoder.decode(NYTimesBestsellerOverview.self, from: data)
                print(overview.num_results)

            } catch let err {
                print("Err", err)
            }
            }.resume()
```

this is my obj:

```swift
import Foundation

struct NYTimesBestsellerOverview: Codable {
    let copyright: String
    let num_results: Int
    let status: String
    let results: Results

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case copyright
        case num_results
        case status
        case results
    }
}

struct Results: Codable {
    var display_name: String
    var published_date: String
    let books: [Book]

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case display_name
        case published_date
        case books
    }
}
```

I keep getting this Error message

> Err typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: The code, the sample json and the error are not matching.

Answer (score 0):

Since your given json `results` key like

> "results": {---}

then it's a dictionary so this

```
let results: Results
```

is correct with this error

> "Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead.

then your response is different than what you posted as a json and it looks like

> "results": [{---}]

to verify do

```
print(String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))
```

---

to fix try

```
let results: [Results]
```

Comment: i got this insteed 
Err keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "published_date", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"published_date\", intValue: nil) (\"published_date\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: make it  optional `var published_date: String?`

Answer (score 0):

Your model seems to have some errors try recreating it using this app from the AppStore: Paste JSON as Code QuickType it is free and you can use various settings you can make all model variables optional. Just paste your JSON into the app and you will get your model generated. Please paste a full copy of a JSON response so that I can help you.